# Ignore non-empty values when aggregating

Tags: ssas

I have a cube I've built with three separate measures: "TY Sales", "LY Sales", and "% Change", what I'm trying to do is have special behavior for the aggregate rows, basically not including any "LY Sales" values when summing the total if "TY Sales" is 0.  So currently my cube works like below:

```
        LYSales  TYSales  %Change
Year 1   450      300     -33%
Week 1   100      125     +25%
Week 2   150      175     +14%
Week 3   200       0      +0%
```

The aggregate column "Year 1" in this example, is summing all values for each sales measure.  What I want it to do instead, is only include values in LYSales if TYSales also has a non-zero value.  So my ideal state would be below:

```
        LYSales  TYSales  %Change
Year 1   250      300     +20%
Week 1   100      125     +25%
Week 2   150      175     +14%
Week 3   200       0      +0%
```

I'm new to SSAS, so any guidance is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy and reliable way to achieve that would be to change the source column of `LYSales` to be zero if TYSales is zero. This would be done in the fact table on which the measure is based. You could implement that

- either in the ETL process, changing the LYSales column values to be zero when TYSales is zero,
- or in a view based on the fact table that is then used in the Data Source View instead of the original table,
- or as a Calculated Calculation of the fact table in the Data Source View.

In the latter two cases, the calculation formula would be SQL like this:

```
case when TYSales <> 0 then LYSales else 0 end
```

Then switch the measure definition to use that column.

Comment: The problem is that I want LYSales to show all values for each individual week, just not be included in the summary row if those values don't have a corresponding TYSales value.  You can see this in the second table, where LYSales for all 3 weeks combined is 450, yet the summary row "Year 1" only shows 250 since it's excluding week 3.  If that makes sense.

Comment: @user2350428 Is this a requirement of one specific query, or more a general requirement that you want to have this calculation applied to whichever query runs against the cube?